# Laravel Queue SerializesModels Trait Removes Related Values

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-queue

Prior to dispatching the job I run an eloquent query joining three tables and selecting data from each of those tables. I pass the result into the job constructor and assign it to $this->data but I believe that the SerializesModels trait is removing all joined data because:

> Because of the SerializesModels trait that the job is using, Eloquent models will be gracefully serialized and unserialized when the job is processing. If your queued job accepts an Eloquent model in its constructor, only the identifier for the model will be serialized onto the queue. When the job is actually handled, the queue system will automatically re-retrieve the full model instance from the database.

So when I go to use $this->data in the handle method all the joined data is gone because the queue system re-retrieved the model instance.

How do I stop this from happening? I don't want to have to rerun a query that was already run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only option is to remove the `SerializesModels` trait which will store the raw data in the table.

What you're experiencing is expected behavior with the trait. This is so that, among other reasons, you don't end up with huge amounts of data stored in the DB from storing the raw model + relations.

Be aware that if you do remove the trait, make sure the column you're storing the data in is significantly large enough to store all of the data, otherwise you'll run into truncation issues.